# Unusual feeling during salah please help (New Muslim)

Tags: quran, salat, hadith-interpretation

Hello Before asking my question let me tell you something about me I was an non Muslim and recently reverted to Muslim about 1 month ago due to my love to Allah . after reverting I started doing all my prayer and reading book for new Muslims and recently I started to do all prayer (Obligatory+Sunnah+Nafl) of all 5 times on their exact time I feel a unusual (can't be expressed) feeling of happiness in my heart and I also do zikr of Almighty "ALLAH " after every 1 hour although I love Islam but from the last week when I pray I get unusual thoughts to leave ISLAM and not to do other non obligatory prayer not to do dhikr and also from few days when I started zikr and doing all my prayer I get an burning sensation sometimes on my body especially at back of my body and my heart beat increases rapidly and sometimes (rarely but day by day getting usual) get very bad thought about ALLAH and about my family member ( I can not say they are too bad) and one thing my parents do not know I am a Muslim and they hate Muslim and I am doing all these prayer by hiding myself Please anyone can tell me is this usual or something serious ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a diagnosis for a very particular condition; this is better-off asked of a trusted professional rather than random strangers on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assalamulaikum,
Firstly I am so happy of the choice you made, welcome my brother/sister! In shaa Allah Allah SWT will ease your journey.

I was born a Muslim, but my family wasn't practicing. Only in the past few years did Allah guide me to learn and complete my prayers and do zikr and search for knowledge.
Looking back, worship was much more difficult in those early days. 
It had mostly to do with forgetting old routines and habits and getting use to a new one. Fasting etc was very hard for me to.
When I prayed I use to always feel exhausted and have headaches. I always felt lazy. But Alhamdullilah eventually it got easier. Some day it is a little stress to manage but it is all for a good reward so we persevere.

So I can say, with time this will In shaa Allah become second nature for you.

I am in the same boat as you, my concentration in prayer slips sometimes. In shaa Allah we both find concentration in our salah and learn to perfect it. Ameen.

Now regarding these thoughts. I know all Muslims it is natural to have a swaying of belief and doubt.

But never give in to them, know that your faith is #1 in your life. It is the most important thing after this life, what did you believe in?
So whenever you find yourself in doubt look up Mufti Menk or Nouman Ali Khan on YouTube, their words usually give some solace. 
Or best of all read The Quran or Islamic teachings. But sometimes it's best to watch scholars talk on YouTube because it is a more authentic place to get accurate interpretations.

Of course, reading about your situation, I immediately feel this is the work of the devil. Whose aim it is to mislead all believers.

May Allah Reward you abundantly with highest reach of Jannah, for taking such a step especially in a household where Islam is not accepted.

I will advise you to read Ayatul Kursi after every prayer session. You can read it here:

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.quran411.com/ayatul-kursi.php

I use to be troubled by a sinister presence in my home, suffered from sleep paralysis etc. But ever since incorporating Ayat Ul Kursi into my prayer routine things have gotten significantly better Alhamdullilah.
You can read about it's benefits on the link provided too, there are many.
I use to read it from my phone after prayer, and naturally it became memorised. Alhamdullilah.

“…Ayat al-Kursi is equal to a quarter of the Qur’an. Whomsoever recites Ayat al-kursi in the night before sleeping, Allah The Most High will protect him, his house & the neighbouring houses…”

(Tafsir Al-Mazhari)

And increase in your adhkar in general. May Allah SWT protect you.

Here is a post of duas you may recite for protection from the devil etc.
https://wayfaringbeliever.tumblr.com/post/169845292450/daily-athkaar-protect-yourselves-dear-brothers

I too am trying to incorporate these duas into my daily routine, I ask Allah to forgive me if I have shared any thing incorrect unknowingly, or taught anything hypocritically.

May Allah Forgive You and Bless You.

Ameen.

Comment: Wa-alaikum-salam thanks for your answer I tried ruqya but I get sleep every time I listen to it and thanks for ayat all kursi and other advice's and for your answer, Amen.

Answer (score 0):

salamunalaikum. it sounds like Satan is coming to you quite often. it quite normal as they are trying to divert you of the straigh path i know this because ive experienced the same things including the burning sensation. inshallah there are ways to protect yourself.

for 100% guaranteed protection in the nights between magreb and fajr recite from surah bakara:
-first 4 versus 
-ayat kursi (verse 155) and 2 verses that follow
-the last 3 versus

these ayats are mentioned in a strong hadeeth that they will protect your home during the night. im unsure weather it will have the same effect during the day as havnt found a strong hadeeth specifying so but its possible that they will. however to be 100 % sure recite surah bakarah and your house will be protected for 3 days

alternatively you can read surah bakarah but its quite dificult but will pretect your house for 3 day if recited in the home at night and same applies if recited during the day

these thoughts might come back if you leave your home so best to remain indoors and keep the house your in protected using these versus

now to coment on the burning sensation my oppinion of why we experience them is that because Allah has elevated us and shown us the truth yet you continue to sin therefore the burning sensation alternatively could be black magic but either way we shouldnt sin try to avoid as much as posssible.
ask allah for forgivnes inshalah the way of prophet younus la ilaha ila ant subhanak ini kuntum mina thalimin
if it is black magic i recomend once again reciting surah bakarah its soo strong. ive read its the best surah and that magicians cant approach it
could also try reading last 3 surahs of quran for protection

inshalah this helps feel free to ask if you have any more questions

Answer (score 0):

#### Assalamualikum

All praise be to Allah and peace be upon his last messenger Hadhrat Muhammed (sallallahu alaihi wa sallam).
Dear brother/sister, i first greet you that Haq subhan wa ta ala has showered his mercy upon you and awarded you with his utmost and invaluable treasure that is imaan. May Allah bestow his long lasting grace on you and keep you on Islam forever and also make you a source of hidayat (right guidance) for others.

my dear brother/sister, the coming of difficulties and unexpected circumstances is part of our examination in this life. From the lives of sahaba radhiallhu, we can see they have endure such circumstances after accepting imaan that we can't even imagine. It is because Allah subhan wa ta ala wants to perfect our imaan. Although He loves us more than seventy times our mother, but He wants His obedient slaves to recognize Him in every aspect of life. That's why such hardships are sent to test our imaan. Swearing shadat of Islam is a first step and enhancing our level of imaan is a life-term work. The more we get our imaan and level of taqwa(piety) enhanced, more we get close to our Creator.

Sahaba radhiallhu did not fear from anything whether it is human, jinn or other creatures, because they fear Allah subhan wa ta ala. A person was brought to Hadrat Abdullah bin masood radhiyallh anhu. This person was suffering from possession of some jin. Hadrat Abdullah bin masood radhiyallh anhu recited the "Afahasibtum annama...."( Surah Muminoon 115-118)  till last in his ear. The deceased person immediately recovered. It can be inferred from this that the sahaba has got this level of imaan by which they were able to remove that jinn in just one time recitation of quran. But our imaan is very weak, although we do also have the same quran as sahaba.
But sahaba have achieved the reality of imaan from the dawat and endurance of hardship.

So my dear be patience with these circumstances and keep complete faith in Allah. Keep doing your prayer sincerely and increase your supplication (especially in last part of night). Also keep reciting quran with intention of cure from these problems. Manzil is a collection of various ayats of quran, selected especially for this purpose, so try to make a day and night habit of reciting manzil. if you need any help, feel free to contact me on "islaah.91@gmail.com".

May Allah subhan wa ta ala accept our deeds and overlook our mistakes and sins

#### Assalamualaikum